# Why mssql2* tag isn't displayed in URL?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have tags in http://stackoverflow.com

[dojo*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo*)

[mssql2*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mssql2*)

First presented in the address bar as `/tagged/dojo*`, but the second one is redirected to only `/questions` but the content is filtered correctly.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why are you adding an asterisk to the tag name? Are you trying to search for any tag that begins with those strings? AFAIK, this simply is not supported...

Comment: @Lix try dojo* vs dojo

Comment: [This works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2*). `mssql*` are synonyms.

Comment: @Mat how to distinguish between tag and synonym when adding tag?

Comment: If you search for "[mssql2005]", you'll see it's automatically changed into "[sql-server-2005]". On that tag's page, there's a "synonyms" link where you can see all the synonyms.

Comment: I think what you're observing is part of a bigger problem in the way wildcard tags are retrieved. For instance, `[*c#*]` only yields `[c#]` results when there are in fact _many_ more tags that contain `c#` in them. I think that due to the bug, `[mssql2*]` is returning no results and therefore takes you to the "all questions" view.